# Start zsh in specified directory

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, gnome-terminal

I can start a new terminal tab with `gnome-terminal --tab zsh`. But now I want to also specify the directory of the new shell.

I couldn't find any options that wouldn't require me to put a `cd` in the `.zshrc`. This is not an option to me, since I want to specify the directory dynamically from the calling command. `zsh -c` doesn't seem to work and piping the command into zsh does not result in an interactive shell (and even if, I doubt I could pass this to the gnome-terminal command).

Comment: Try `gnome-terminal --working-directory=directoryName --tab zsh`

Comment: This does not work for me. Edit: Okay it does now, I had to expand the ~ manually for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add the `--working-directory` option.

From [man gnome-terminal](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html):

> --working-directory=DIRNAME
>                    Set the terminal's working directory to DIRNAME

So your command would be:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=DIRNAME --tab zsh
```

Comment: This is weird, I don't have the man page